# How to test history.pushState and window.addEventListener using jasmine

Tags: jquery, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I am trying to test my piece of code using jasmine. But the jasmine code is giving error.

*Code :*

```
self.monitorRoutes = function () {

  var pageRef = window.location.href.split('#').pop();

  history.pushState(null,pageRef, pageRef);

}
```

*Jasmine Code :*

```
it('monitor routes', function () {

   spyOn(history, 'pushState')

   viewmodel.monitorRoutes();
});
```

*Error :*
**TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'history.pushState')**

how could I mock pushState using jasmine?
I am facing same issue for window.addEventListener